# What does the --pre option in pip signify?

Tags: python, pip

I saw on [this](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j_doc_manager) page that `pip install neo4j-doc-manager --pre` was used. What does the `--pre` flag mean?

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#pre-release-versions

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It tells `pip` to include pre-release versions of packages when searching for the latest version.

From the [`pip install` reference documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#install-pre):

> Include pre-release and development versions. By default, pip only finds stable versions.

See the [section on *Pre-release Versions*](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#pre-release-versions):

> Starting with v1.4, pip will only install stable versions as specified by PEP426 by default. If a version cannot be parsed as a compliant PEP426 version then it is assumed to be a pre-release.

The `neo4j-doc-manager` package currently has 5 releases out; one 'stable' 0.1.0 release and 4 `devX` releases which are newer, see the [machine-readable list of releases](https://pypi.python.org/simple/neo4j-doc-manager/). Without the `--pre` switch the `0.1.0` release would be installed, with the switch (as of this writing) `1.0.0.dev11` would be installed instead.

Comment: Why would anyone wants to install with --pre option when there is a stable release by default?  Thanks

Comment: To get or test a feature that is no yet available in the stable version.

Comment: Or to be able to use a prerelease that supports newer versions of a dependency. Can be relevant for security issues, such as here. https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/1685#issuecomment-1201280098

Answer (score 6):

> The pip install command also supports a --pre flag that will enable
> installing pre-releases and development releases.

[Source](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-pre).