# How to solve the "pip install pygame" issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, pygame

I am trying to use command `pip install pygame` in cmd, but there is error.
The error is shown as follows:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/2c/3a52e7e9c097229b026b4efbe6711c600f3a84ffdc5f11fd9e7f8932368e/pygame-1.9.6-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
Installing collected packages: pygame
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] 拒绝访问。: 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python37-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pygame'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I follow the instruction in the error but still cannot solve the problem. And I also found whatever "pip" command cannot be installed correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install -r: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+EnvironmentError+WinError+5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the package as Administrator, by following these steps:

1.Right click on the Command Prompt icon
2.Select the option: Run This Program As An Administrator
3.Run the command: pip install pygames

Instead of you can use the command
`pip install --user pygames`

Comment: Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/2c/3a52e7e9c097229b026b4efbe6711c600f3a84ffdc5f11fd9e7f8932368e/pygame-1.9.6-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
Installing collected packages: pygame
Successfully installed pygame-1.9.6
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers didn't work for me. I checked [this site](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1.html) and made sure that pip, setuptools, and ez_setup were installed at the latest versions. Still no luck. Finally, I discovered the magic words [here](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/2292):

```
pip install pygame --pre
```

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35131910/5257294), `--pre` option tells pip to include pre-release versions of packages when searching for the latest version. Apparently that's what's needed as of this writing (2023-02-08).

(Thanks to `accddd`)

Comment: Running as administrator and updating pip did not work for me, but this did. Thanks!

Comment: As of 3/5/2023, the --pre is no longer required

Answer (score -1):

check if Pip was installed correctly by opening a command prompt and entering the following command:

```
pip -V
```

output should be like:

```
 pip 18.0 from c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

if pip is not install copy this file [link](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and save it to setup.py
now open cmd and run script by typing

```
python setup.py
```

for more details check [link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).

when pip in install correctly install run this commond

```
python -m pip install -u pygame --user
```

Answer (score -1):

For this, you have to install **pygame** package from the cmd (on Windows) or from the terminal (on mac). Just type **pip** install pygame.If it doesn't work for you, then try using this statement **pip3** install pygame. If it is still showing an error then you don't have pip installed on your device and try installing pip first.