# Error: subprocess-exited-with -error. --python

Tags: python, python-3.x, model, midi

Error: subprocess-exited-with -error, python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
I know that there are some similar questions. But the error still exist after trying those solution. I want to install a model called [midi-ddsp](https://github.com/magenta/midi-ddsp)  and it shows an error.

```
Requirement already satisfied: music21 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from midi-ddsp) (7.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from midi-ddsp) (1.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pretty-midi in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from midi-ddsp) (0.2.9)
Requirement already satisfied: mir-eval in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from ddsp==3.2.0->midi-ddsp) (0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-addons in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from ddsp==3.2.0->midi-ddsp) (0.17.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cloudml-hypertune in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from ddsp==3.2.0->midi-ddsp) (0.1.0.dev6)
Collecting crepe>=0.0.11
  Using cached crepe-0.0.12.tar.gz (15 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
```

Because the codes are too long, if I need to paste more, please tell me!

I've tried to `upgrade pip`, `pip3 install midi-ddsp --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver`, `pip3 install --upgrade setuptools`, `easy_install -U setuptools`  and so on. But neither of them could work. Hope someone could help me, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I got this exact same error when trying to run:

```
pip install dotenv
```

After a lot of hunting around, I realised I got the package name wrong.  The correct command was:

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

Maybe try googling "pip your-package-name" to find the [PyPi](https://pypi.org/) page for your package and double check you are using the correct name?  It is annoying that the pip error message was not more descriptive.

Comment: God thanks I was beating my head trying to figure out why I couldn't install dotenv

Comment: I was having the same exact issue and this is what solved it.

Answer (score 3):

I tried these from the answers of another question on StackOverflow but didn't work for me

```
pip install --user pygames
python -m pip install -u pygame --user
```

([How to solve the "pip install pygame" issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56720753/how-to-solve-the-pip-install-pygame-issue))

### **But in the end, I tried along with --pre. This worked**

```
pip install pygame --pre
```

**Output:**

```
PS C:\\Windows\\system32\> pip install pygame --pre
Collecting pygame
Using cached pygame-2.1.3.dev8-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (10.6 MB)
Installing collected packages: pygame
Successfully installed pygame-2.1.3.dev8
```

**I think `--pre` is used for**
*[The pip install command also supports a --pre flag that enables installation of pre-releases and development releases.](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/search/?q=--pre&check_keywords=yes&area=default)*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to import an old requirements.txt.
`scipy==1.5.1`
I checked it from Pypi, changed to 1.9.1 in requirements.txt,
and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on updating `systemd-python` with

```
python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade systemd-python
```

The error message began with these words:

```
 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
```

The lines following were quite telling:

```
Cannot find libsystemd or libsystemd-journal:
      
Package libsystemd was not found in the pkg-config search path.
```

Even though the package `libsystemd` was installed, Python did not find it. I have learnt that often you can solve this "not finding an installed package" by installing the corresponding `dev` package; in this case it is `libsystemd-dev`.

After installing the `libsystemd-dev` the command `python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade systemd-python` ran smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

If using pip3

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

If pip is not in PATH

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip

  python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

For Windows

```
py -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Upgrade setuptools and wheel

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools wheel
python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel
python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel
py -m pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel
```