# pip install web3 in python did not run successfully

Tags: python, blockchain, web3py

I want to install the web3py library to deploy a smart contract in blockchain and I'm faced with this issue. How can I fix it?

```
 error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ?─> [5 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'lru' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lru-dict
  Running setup.py clean for lru-dict
Failed to build lru-dict
Installing collected packages: lru-dict, bitarray, websockets, toolz, six, pyrsistent, pycryptodome, protobuf, multidict, hexbytes, frozenlist, eth-typing, eth-hash, charset-normalizer, base58, attrs, async-timeout, yarl, parsimonious, multiaddr, jsonschema, cytoolz, aiosignal, ipfshttpclient, eth-utils, aiohttp, rlp, eth-keys, eth-abi, eth-rlp, eth-keyfile, eth-account, web3
  Running setup.py install for lru-dict ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for lru-dict did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ?─> [7 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'lru' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
?─> lru-dict

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what isn't clear about the error text? `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`

Comment: Have you tried using `pip install web3 --pre`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73183609/error-subprocess-exited-with-error-python

Comment: Are you a C++ tool creator?

Answer (score -1):

It Was Not Working With python 3.11 but its working with python3.9 where i use python 3.9.6 check with that. It Works perfect