# Issue installing transformers

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I'm doing a NLP project on vscode " amazon reviews sentiment analyzer" every thing is going ok until I reached the part for importing transformers

when I'm installing transformers from pip Im getting this error :

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
```

I tried downloading rust and cargo and it didn't work
I'm sure its in the environment variable It the first time I do NLTK project .

Comment: If your title is longer than your post, it's not a title. [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: subprocess-exited-with -error. --python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73183609/error-subprocess-exited-with-error-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can [read document](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers#with-pip) about how to install this package.

You will need to install at least one of **Flax**, **PyTorch**, or **TensorFlow**.

When one of those backends has been installed, Transformers can be installed using pip as follows:

```
pip install transformers
```

Comment: Thankyou I installed Tensorflow and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Rust and Cargo installed. If installed, check your PATH environment variables to ensure it includes path to Rust and Cargo

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to install tensorflow to my environment.

Comment: Hi hassan issa, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also can I answer my own question.., Just a reminder :)